# Android - WiFi API for Android 2.2 or 2.3

Tags: android, api

I have to make a **peer to peer file sharing app** on **android platform**

Can someone tell me about the **WiFi API** that i can use for it and how can i get these API's

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad for SO. This platform is meant for specific programming questions (i.e. you've already done the research, and tried something but are having trouble. Post your troubles and we'll try to help)

search around on the developer site some. Here is a page that might be of interest to you to get started: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html